# how to run multiple php files at the same time?

Tags: php, nginx

build environment nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu 20.04) / php7.4-fpm

i'm confused about php multi-threading capabilities, i know that it doesn't support it in stock build and it requires a PHP build with ZTS (Zend Thread Safety) to go with pthreads or parallel

pthreads seems experimental, unsafe and not fit for server environment so that leaves parallel as for the more suitable option

what i'm trying to accomplish isn't complicated, i just want the server to run a query every second or so looking for new data in a mysql database to serve it through a phpwebsocket without the server halting everything when it starts the query loop because php can't chew gum and walk at the same time.

currently if client 1 loads php page A, he can't access any other pages until page A is done running, yet other clients can still access other pages when client 1 is still running page A which makes me think that it is single threaded per session.

the alternative is having the client side doing it with repeating ajax request, but that seems to be bandwidth wasting and inefficient.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have misunderstood what's happening. You don't need multi-threading to serve multiple web pages at once, and keeping a process running to serve a websocket connection isn't going to make everything else grind to a halt.

> currently if client 1 loads php page A, he can't access any other pages until page A is done running, yet other clients can still access other pages when client 1 is still running page A which makes me think that it is single threaded per session.

The word "session" here is probably the key to your actual problem: PHP's [session support](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php) uses exclusive locking by default. When you call `session_start()` to load an existing session, the default implementation reads a file on disk, *and locks it until the end of the request* or until you call `session_write_close()`. Other attempts to read the same session data will wait until the lock is released. This prevents corruption caused by different requests writing conflicting versions of the same session, but it means that the user will see a delay if they open multiple pages in parallel.

The solution is simple: if you have a long-running request, don't run `session_start()`, or if you need to read the session, immediately run `session_write_close()` to unlock it for use by other requests.